# With regards to razor, what is difference between .NET MVC support for razor vs .NET razor pages and is there anything called .NET MVC razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

.NET presently has 5 ways to build web sites that produce the content via trip to the server:

- .NET framework 4.8 - MVC (ignore this for the purpose of this question)
- .NET framework 4.8 - Web forms (ignore this for the purpose of this question)
- .NET MVC with support for razor
- .NET Razor pages
- Blazor (ignore this for the purpose of this question)

**Question 1:** I am trying to understand - with regards to the concept of razor, what is the difference between .NET MVC support for razor vs .NET razor pages? I will attempt to give my understanding below:

- I know that point 1 is MVC. Point 2 is MVVM.
- I know that - .NET MVC support for razor are MVC (model, view, controller concept) with support for razor syntax on the view pages, without any code-behind (I mean that the logic is at the controller level). Whereas .NET razor pages are the MVVM approach like the page (razor syntax) and code behind.

Is this correct?

**Question 2:** I heard my colleague talk about **.NET MVC razor pages**. I am confused because I have never come across such a thing. My understanding is that .NET MVC is different to .NET Razor pages. Is there anything called .NET MVC razor pages?

**Question 3:** This article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/modern-web-applications-characteristics#traditional-and-spa-behaviors-supported) mentions:

> ASP.NET Core supports both MVC (Views or Page based)

How can MVC be page based when the name (MVC) itself says it is view based? Can someone give me clarity on this?

Comment: You'd answer all your questions if you actually read the docs and did the tutorials instead of looking for some academic definition. Razor is a marketing name. It's used for the syntax used by **all** web stacks after WebForms (MVC, Pages, Blazor). The view engine used by MVC is called Razor Engine because it uses the Razor syntax. Pages isn't an MVVM implementation, that's why they call the class a PageModel, not a ViewModel. Every MVVM framework since Backbone behaves differently.

Comment: Your questions are already answered in [Choose an ASP.NET Core web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/choose-web-ui?view=aspnetcore-6.0). There's no such thing as `.NET MVC Razor Pages`. But you *can* use both MVC and Pages in the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is a templating syntax. It enables C# to be embedded in HTML so that you can use C# to generate part of the HTML dynamically at runtime.

MVC is a server-side development framework that encourages you to use the Model-View-Controller architecture for building your web applications. It uses Razor for its default View engine.

Razor Pages is an alternative server-side development framework, which relies on a page-centric approach to web application development. It uses Razor as its templating syntax.

MVVM is a design pattern that is used in applications that run on the client - for example, WPF, Xamarin and some Javascript-based SPA frameworks. I've seen it used to describe Razor Pages, but I don't agree, and feel that calling Razor Pages MVVM just causes confusion.

ASP.NET Core MVC encourages a "front Controller" approach, in that a single controller can be responsible for processing multiple routes, whose only connection is that they relate to the same entity. Razor Pages can also be seen as an implementation of MVC that uses a Page Controller approach instead. The PageModel class is analogous to a controller for the page.

Comment: In MVC all requests go to the controller and the controller decides which view is to be given to the user. When we have a razor page in mvc rather than the view, then does the request still go to the controller and does the controller invoke the Razor page?

Comment: In Razor Pages, there is a one-to-one relationship between the "view" (the .cshtml file) and its "controller" (the PageModel class). In the MVC framework, there is a one-to-many relationship between the controller and its views. Technically, the controller doesn't decide which view the user gets. An action selector component determines which method on which controller gets invoked to process a request based on its URL.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that Razor pages is like having controller with only one method. And can I ask whether routing module is able to handle situation wherein both MVC and Razor pages are in the same project?

Comment: Yes it can handle both MVC controllers and Razor Pages.